# Missing translation problem with react-native-localize even though the translation exist

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a problem with missing translation even though the translation exits,

```
const translationGetters = {
  en: () => require('./translations/en.json'),
  de: () => require('./translations/de.json'),
};

const translate = memoize(
  (key, config) => i18n.t(key, config),
  (key, config) => (config ? key + JSON.stringify(config) : key),
);

const setI18nConfig = () => {
  // fallback if no available language fits
  const fallback = {languageTag: 'en', isRTL: false};

  const {languageTag, isRTL} =
    RNLocalize.findBestAvailableLanguage(Object.keys(translationGetters)) ||
    fallback;

  // clear translation cache
  translate.cache.clear();
  // update layout direction
  I18nManager.forceRTL(isRTL);
  // set i18n-js config
  i18n.translations = {[languageTag]: translationGetters[languageTag]()};
  i18n.locale = languageTag;
};

const App = () => {
  handleLocalizationChange = () => {
    setI18nConfig()
      .then(() => this.forceUpdate())
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setI18nConfig();

    RNLocalize.addEventListener('change', handleLocalizationChange);

    return () => {
      RNLocalize.removeEventListener('change', handleLocalizationChange);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={ThemeRed}>
      <AppContainer />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

and in HomeScreen

```
import i18n from 'i18n-js';

const HomeScreen = ({...props}) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.mainView}>
      <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>{i18n.t('welcome')}</Text>
   </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

can anyone help to see what I'm doing wrong.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am facing the example same problem.

Comment: me too having same issue +1

Comment: Same issue. Did you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think in homescreen during translating one has to import the `translate` function and use `{translate('home')}` instead of `i18n.t()` in Homescreen/any screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a quite similar question 2 days ago: [How to use setLocale within i18n-js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59949722/how-to-use-setlocale-within-i18n-js/59955991#59955991)

I was not using `react-native-localize` but `expo-localization` but I don't this is an issue. You are still using `i18n-js` like I do, so it may apply.